# How to set a row index in python when the column index changes?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read in a csv of company financial information. The row index name is always changing though depending on the company (for instance with facebook the row index name is "Fiscal year ends in December. USD in millions except per share data." but for another company it will say fiscal year ends January...)
How would I be able to keep that first column name consistent? I made an attempt by renaming the columns but it throws an error.

```
stock = "FB"
#Import the data
Ratios = pd.read_csv("http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/exportKR2CSV.html?t="+stock, skiprows=2)
incomeStatement = pd.read_csv("http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4CSV.html?t="+stock+"&reportType=is&period=3&dataType=A&order=asc&columnYear=5&number=3", skiprows = 1)
balSheet = pd.read_csv("http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4CSV.html?t="+stock+"&reportType=bs&period=3&dataType=A&order=asc&columnYear=5&number=3", skiprows = 1)

incomeStatement.columns(['Title','Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4','Q5', 'TTM'])
balSheet.columns(['Title','Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4','Q5', 'TTM'])
#Set the columns
Ratios.set_index("Unnamed: 0", inplace=True)
incomeStatement.set_index("Title", inplace=True)
balSheet.set_index("Title", inplace=True)
```

This will work but that set index name will always change for different companys.

```
stock = "FB"
#Import the data
Ratios = pd.read_csv("http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/exportKR2CSV.html?t="+stock, skiprows=2)
incomeStatement = pd.read_csv("http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4CSV.html?t="+stock+"&reportType=is&period=3&dataType=A&order=asc&columnYear=5&number=3", skiprows = 1)
balSheet = pd.read_csv("http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4CSV.html?t="+stock+"&reportType=bs&period=3&dataType=A&order=asc&columnYear=5&number=3", skiprows = 1)


#Set the columns
Ratios.set_index("Unnamed: 0", inplace=True)
incomeStatement.set_index("Fiscal year ends in December. USD in millions except per share data.", inplace=True)
balSheet.set_index("Fiscal year ends in December. USD in millions except per share data.", inplace=True)
```

Here is an example of the output:
[Resulting Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfPHT.png)
where I want the index to be the first column but the name of that row (fiscal year ends december...) will be changing for each iteration.

Comment: can you elaborate a little more with an example output maybe?

Comment: Just added a screenshot of the output before setting the index.

Comment: you can split the dataframe into multiple columns and combine them with index. Then join them based on those index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `read_csv`, there is actually an argument to set the index column immediately:

```
Ratios = pd.read_csv("http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/exportKR2CSV.html?t="+stock, skiprows=2,index_col = 0)
```

`index_col = 0` ensures the resulting data frame will use the first (0th index) column as the index, and give the index the appropriate title if the file contains a header.

Answer (score 0):

Use csv.DictReader and set the fieldnames (or headers)